# Spherical Cake and the egg slicer

Tags: calculus, volume, spherical-geometry, fair-division

Recently I baked a spherical cake (3cm radius) and invited over a few friends, 6 of them, for dinner. When done with main course, I thought of serving this spherical cake and to avoid uninvited disagreements over the size of the shares, I took my egg slicer with equally spaced  wedges(and designed to cut 6 slices at a go; my slicer has 5 wedges spaced at 1 cm apart) and placed my spherical cake right in the exact middle of it before pressing uniformly upon the slicer. Was I successful in avoiding the feuds over the shares. If so then what could be the mathematical explanation of it and if not then why not? My Setup looked a bit similar like given in the image below:

[image: slicer]

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the setup, preferably with a drawing?

Comment: @An.Ditlev : I do not know if its agood idea but I included this image similar to the setup of mine.

Comment: Look up the volume of a spherical cap in Wikipedia. You want each slice to be $1/6$ of the total volume. Find the height of a cap that gives this and the height that gives $1/3$. Those heights plus the center are what you want.

Comment: Please see the question I posted after this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926383/equal-slicing-of-my-spherical-cake

Comment: My comment still applies. Your second question just removes the given value of$r$, so the desired locations will scale with $r$

Comment: Yes thanks for the Wikepedia reference.I just looked at it and I see the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean something like [this](http://calculus.seas.upenn.edu/uploads/Main/SphereSlices.png) (although this is intended for five persons). If so, then that is obviously not a fair way of dividing the cake (the other slices will be much smaller than the inner slices).

Comment: I guess if I have 5 wedges on my slicer I would be able to cut 6 slices intended for 6 friends.

Comment: @naveendankal Yes. It would be an interesting problem to figure out how the wedges should be placed relative to one another so that the division of cake was fair.

Comment: Also I was wondering if the "Buldge on the "outer" slices (on the sides) due to the spherical shape" would be able to "accomodate" for the "thickness" of the inner slices.

Comment: @naveendankal They are all the same width (1 cm), but the outer slices have a smaller radius, so they are smaller.

Comment: @Lavsovs: should I modify my question to include how wedges should be placed to make a fair division.

Comment: @naveendankal No, better to make a new question about that (and give it some more thought beforehand).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45350/discussion-between-naveen-dankal-and-lovsovs).