# Solving $x+x^3=5$ without using the cubic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, cubics

In lessons, I get quite bored and recently throughout these lessons I have been trying to solve for x in:
$$x+x^3=5$$

I've figured out how to do it for squares using the quadratic equation, but the cubic equation looks so dauntingly massive it actually makes my bladder hurt.

So, is there a way to figure this out using a different process, and better so for $x^n$.

Danke Chien

Comment: When you say $x^n$, do you mean a general polynomial of order $n$, or the specific polynomial $x + x^n = 5$?  In general, it is not possible to find a closed-form solution to the zeroes of any polynomial of degree greater than 5.  This isn't just a "we don't know how", it's provably impossible to do.

Comment: I'm afraid the only way to solve this one is using the [general cubic forumla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) which is painful and the final answer [WA](http://tinyurl.com/zqaxzxj) gives is ugly.

Comment: Aside: Bertrand Russell said something like "mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses a supreme beauty, cold and austere, like that of sculpture". Is it the cold that makes your bladder hurt? $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm talking about because I'm twelve but: $\frac{d}{dx}x^3 = 3x^2$ could you not use this in any way shape or form?

Comment: @OllyBritton Oh yeah, that makes no sense in this context.  You're twelve... how'd you even know *of* that?  :D

Comment: @OllyBritton, too young to start with bladder pains ,  so  it  might relieve you a bit knowing that a much more affordable way to compute the solutions of a cubic equation is given in [this paper by A. Cauli](http://ebook-kings.com/pdf/risoluzione-delle-equazioni-di-terzo-e-quarto-5800324.html )   (in italian) and summarized in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928332/how-to-show-that-the-roots-of-x33x-left2-frac4n-right-0-are-real-a/1928624#1928624)

Comment: You cold also put it into a grapher and zoom in really, really close.

Comment: @OllyBritton Hm, I'll post an answer in that spirit.

Answer (score 2):

See that we have the beautiful trigonometric identity

$$\sinh(3\operatorname{arcsinh}(r))=4r^3+3r$$

Which can be used here.

To give a definition of the above,

$$\sinh(r)=\frac{e^r-e^{-r}}2$$

$$\operatorname{arcsinh}(r)=\ln(r+\sqrt{r^2+1})$$

where we have the natural exponential function and the natural logarithm.  Particularly, $e\approx2.718281828\dots$  As for logarithms, you'll have to study up on that.

So, we proceed as follows:

$$5=x^3+x$$

Multiply both sides by $\frac{3\sqrt3}2$

$$5\left(\frac{3\sqrt3}2\right)=\left(\frac{3\sqrt3}2\right)(x^3+x)$$

$$\frac{15\sqrt3}2=\frac{3\sqrt3}2x^3+\frac{3\sqrt3}2x$$

Substitute $x=\frac{2\sqrt3}3y$

$$\frac{15\sqrt3}2=\frac{3\sqrt3}2\left(\frac{2\sqrt3}3y\right)^3+\frac{3\sqrt3}2\left(\frac{2\sqrt3}3y\right)$$

$$\frac{15\sqrt3}2=4y^3+3y$$

Use the tigonometric identity

$$\frac{15\sqrt3}2=4y^3+3y=\sinh(3\operatorname{arcsinh}(y))$$

$$\frac{15\sqrt3}2=\sinh(3\operatorname{arcsinh}(y))$$

$$\underbrace{\operatorname{arcsinh}(\sinh}_{\text{cancellation}}(3\operatorname{arcsinh}(y)))=\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{15\sqrt3}2\right)$$

$$3\operatorname{arcsinh}(y)=\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{15\sqrt3}2\right)$$

$$\operatorname{arcsinh}(y)=\frac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{15\sqrt3}2\right)$$

$$\underbrace{\sinh(\operatorname{arcsinh}}_{\text{cancellation}}(y)=\sinh\left(\frac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{15\sqrt3}2\right)\right)$$

$$y=\sinh\left(\frac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{15\sqrt3}2\right)\right)$$

Multiply both sides by $\frac{2\sqrt3}3$

---

> $$x=\frac{2\sqrt3}3y=\frac{2\sqrt3}3\sinh\left(\frac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{15\sqrt3}2\right)\right)$$

which is equivalent to Robert's answer.

Answer (score 2):

A trick for solving this equation goes back to Viète (but is not much different from Tartaglia's and Cardano's method).

Set $x=y-\dfrac{1}{3y}$. Then
$$
x^3+x=y^3-y+\frac{1}{3y}-\frac{1}{27y^3}+y-\frac{1}{3y}=
y^3-\frac{1}{27y^3}
$$
so your equation becomes, after setting $z=y^3$,
$$
z-\frac{1}{27z}=5
$$
This becomes a quadratic:
$$
27z^2-135z-1=0
$$
and so
$$
z=\frac{135\pm\sqrt{18333}}{54}=\frac{45\pm\sqrt{2037}}{18}
$$
Let's take the root with $+$; then
$$
y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{45+\sqrt{2037}}{18}}
$$
and so
$$
x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{45+\sqrt{2037}}{18}}-
\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{18}{45+\sqrt{2037}}}\approx 1.51598
$$
You can check that taking the other root yields the same solution.

In case the equation is $x^3+px=q$, the substitution is
$$
x=y-\frac{p}{3y}
$$
because in this case we get
$$
x^3+px=y^3-py+\frac{p^2}{3y}-\frac{p^3}{27y^3}+py-\frac{p^2}{3y}
=y^3-\frac{p^3}{27y^3}
$$
Setting $z=y^3$, we get the quadratic
$$
27z^2-27qz-p^3=0
$$
which has real roots if and only if
$$
27^2q^2+4\cdot27p^3\ge0
$$
that can be written
$$
\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}\ge0
$$
It turns out that the equation $x^3+px=q$ has just one real root when $q^2/4+p^3/27>0$ and a double (or triple) root when $q^2/4+p^3/27=0$.

What happens when $q^2/4+p^3/27<0$? That's the *big* question: it is the case when the equation has *three distinct roots*. The method still works, but it necessarily involves the complex numbers, if an algebraic expression of the roots is needed.

Viète devised a trigonometric method for getting approximate values of the roots in the case $q^2/4+p^3/27<0$.

OK, let's try another one: $x^3+x=2$. The quadratic becomes
$$
27z^2-54z-1=0
$$
which has a root
$$
z=\frac{9+\sqrt{84}}{9}
$$
and so
$$
x=
\sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{84}}{9}}-
\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{9+\sqrt{84}}}
$$
which is just a complicated way to write $1$.

Comment: Mhm, the $x=y+1/y$ came out nicely here.

Comment: @SimpleArt The last example aims to show that the technique is not guaranteed to yield the ”best“ representation of a root.

Comment: @egreg How do you simplify the $z-\frac{1}{27z}$ into $27z^2-135z-1$

Comment: @OllyBritton It's the whole equation $z-\frac{1}{27z}=5$ that becomes $27z^2-135z-1=0$ (multiply both sides by $27z$).

Comment: @egreg Should've used the example $0=x^3-3x+1$ to show you need overly complicated complex numbers to represent the roots (or trig you know)

Comment: @SimpleArt Even better, $x^3-7x=6$.

Comment: @egreg For the $x=3$ huh?  Kids, this is why you should learn rational roots theorem first

Comment: @SimpleArt It's a good example of how blindly following “rules” can take nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write a solution is
$$ x = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \sinh\left(\frac{1}{3} \text{arcsinh}\left( \frac{15}{2} \sqrt{3}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Can you please  explain this...

Comment: [Hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function).  This solution is based on the identity $\sinh(3 x) = 4 \sinh(x)^3 + 3 \sinh(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$  \sqrt[3] { \frac{5}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{679}{108}}   } +   \sqrt[3] { \frac{5}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{679}{108}}   }  \approx 1.51598 $$
OR
$$  \sqrt[3] {  \; \; \sqrt{\frac{679}{108}} + \frac{5}{2} \; \;  } \; \; - \; \;   \sqrt[3] { \; \; \sqrt{\frac{679}{108}} - \frac{5}{2} \; \;   }   \approx 1.51598 $$

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about this value ? By curiosity I entered it in Mathematica and it does not match the approximation you give and does not seem to fit in the equation.

Comment: @Zubzub note that $679/ 108 \approx 6.287037,$ so $\sqrt {679/108} \approx 2.507396$ is slightly bigger than $2.5.$ The second cube root is therefore negative.

Comment: You're right, I just figured it out, sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is difficult to find roots in closed form, so this answer is in the spirit of numerical values for the roots:

$$x^3+x=5$$

$$x^2+1=\frac5x$$

$$x^2=\frac5x-1=\frac{5-x}x$$

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{5-x}x}$$

Once you solve for $x$, you can employ fixed-point iteration.  First, see the root is near $x=1.5$

$$x_0=1.5$$

$$x_1=\sqrt{\frac{5-x_0}{x_0}}=\sqrt{\frac{5-1.5}{1.5}}=\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}=1.527525231651947$$

$$x_2=\sqrt{\frac{5-{x_1}}{x_1}}=1.507736168412725$$

$$x_3=\sqrt{\frac{5-x_2}{x_2}}=1.521916573662357$$

And you can keep doing this until you find an answer out as many decimals you want.

---

A much better algorithm to use is Newton's method:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{(x_n)^3+x_n-5}{3(x_n)^2+1}$$

Starting with $x_0=1.5$ again,

$$x_0=1.5$$

$$x_1=1.5-\frac{1.5^3+1.5-5}{3(1.5)^2+1}=1.516129032258065$$

$$x_2=1.51598024045$$

Admittedly more complicated, but the amount of digits correct just about doubles each time, which is far faster than the fixed point iteration method.  Also note this already captures all of the digits Will Jagy gives us.